# Non selected cells being affected when using Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)'

Tags: vba, excel, selection

I have created a macro that adds a prefix to the current selection. It's pretty simple as you can see - it loops through visible cells in the selection. I added the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` because it was affecting unintended cells when using filters.

```
Sub Prefix()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Prefix As String
Prefix = "P"

For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng = Prefix & rng
Next rng

End Sub
```

As an example, assume that my data is `Cells A1:A4` filled out like this:

```
Title
1
2
1
```

My problem occurs when I do the following:

1. Put an `Autofilter` on the range, and hide the '2' that is in A3
2. Select A2 (the first '1')
3. Run my macro

The problem is that instead of affecting only `Cell A2` (the selected cell), it starts applying the prefix to the first row (A1:Z1 , etc.) until I cancel the macro. It will keep doing this to thousands of cells if I let it keep running.

This problem doesn't happen when my selection is multiple cells, or if I use `Selection` rather than `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, or if I apply the macro to one cell when nothing is being filtered out (hidden).

Does anyone have any ideas why the selection defaults to the whole spreadsheet when I only have one cell selected?
Alternatively, can anyone suggest a way to add prefixes like this using VBA?

I am aware that using an excel formula would alleviate the problem but that is not practical for me and regardless is not as fast as clicking a macro.

Comment: Most likely because your sub has no idea what the Selection is so it uses the whole sheet. Add a range parameter for the range you want this to work on and pass that in to the sub. Replace Selection with that parameter and it should work.

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by adding the range parameter? I know that I could run the sub to work on Range("a2:a4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) or something like that but I want to be able to use it on a selection rather than editing the macro each time. I might apply to 10 different selection in a row that are not next to each other so not worth the time to edit the macro code each time.

Comment: If you want it to work like that it would have to be in the worksheet selection change event. I'll post something shortly

Comment: And when you say prefix, are you just wanting to add the p to the value in the cell? Because right now your code shouldn't work as you are not using Set for rng in your for loop.

Comment: p was an example yeah. What I'ma actually doing is adding country code prefixes so I'm using inputbox to decide what the code should be depending on what country the number is from.

Sub Prefix()

'Dim rng As Range
'Dim Prefix As String
'Prefix = InputBox("Enter the prefix, e.g: +91", "Prefix")


`For Each rng In selection '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
`rng = VBA.replace(rng, "-", " ")`
`rng = Prefix & rng `
`Next rng`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Application.intersect' to make sure you get your desired result:

```
For each rng in Application.Intersect(Selection,ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

Comment: It still needs to know what selection is

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work dynamically when you select a range of cells manually AND your intent is to just prepend the country code from the input box to the current value of the cell, then add the change event posted below to the code section of your worksheet and add the routine to a code module in the workbook.

Not sure why you are doing the replace of the minus sign, but you can add it to this code if needed.

Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call AddPrefix(Target)
End Sub
```

Add a module and put this code in it.

```
Sub AddPrefix(rangeToPrefix)
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim prefix As String
    prefix = InputBox("Enter your country code", "Set Country Code", +33)

    For Each cCell In rangeToPrefix.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not IsEmpty(cCell) Then cCell.Value = prefix & cCell.Value
    Next cCell
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. This is quite tough to turn on and off, and requires a little work to use on a second occasion. I'm also struggling to use it without it sometimes deciding to apply the change to the whole worksheet (and thus crashing excel) , seemingly at random, but presumably I'm misusing it somehow.

I think an alternative would be to use my original method, but with an `If` that checks whether `selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` produces an error, and if it does, to use `selection` instead.

Comment: The code I posted should only change cell values that you manually select with your mouse(which triggers the selectionchange event) and if a cell is empty it t change the value.